# Increase max_components variable in dedupe library

Tags: python, pyspark, record-linkage, python-dedupe

How can I increase default value in `max_components` variable?

By default `max_components` is set to 30000. I need increase this limit because every time I do deduplications (using the same datasets) I have different results.

I think that the total amount of clusters in my data is bigger than 30000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Github

[Issue in dedupe github Increase max_components = 30000](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/issues/600)

> If you are getting different results using same saved settings file,
>   then what you reporting is a bug. If you are getting different results
>   from different training data (or even the same training data), that's
>   expected as at various points dedupe uses a random sample to learn
>   good rules.
>
> In either case, I doubt that max_components is related. But, if you
>   want to change it, fork the code and change it.